# Using Swing components in JavaFX 2

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

i am using JavaFx2.Can any one give me the samples of integrating the swing components in JavaFX.I am searching for this from 2 days but i didn't get the correct solution.Some one is telling it is not possible in JavaFX2 and some one is telling it is simple.I am totally getting confuse.If it is possible can you share me the links or any samples.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

> i am using JavaFx2.Can any one give me the samples of integrating the
>   swing components in JavaFX

- this not possible for current `JavaFX 2.x`, this intergration (vice versa Swing and JavaFx) is in development, testing and will be possible in `Java8` with `JavaFX8`
- all important (new, roadmap, rellase candinates) is on [FX Experience](http://fxexperience.com/)