# Non continuous slider

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to have following slider where user can select only predefined set of values (64, 128, 256, ... 2048) and I also want to be able set labels for this ticks. Something like this:

```
[--*---------*------------------O--------------]
   64       128                256
```

Is there any built-in solution or component for such non continuous slider?

Comment: this seems like you just label the ticks with powers of 2...

Comment: @Randy you are absolutely correct :)

Comment: then does the normal Swing control work?

Comment: @Randy is it possible to integrate swing components to javafx2 application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725762/using-swing-components-in-javafx-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is for JavaFX-8 (it is not applicable for JFX-2 because of issue, watch comment below) :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Slider s = new Slider();
    s.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Double t) {
            return String.valueOf(Math.round(Math.pow(2, t)));
        }

        @Override
        public Double fromString(String string) {
            return Double.parseDouble(string);
        }
    });

    s.setMin(0);
    s.setMax(10);
    s.setMajorTickUnit(1);
    s.setMinorTickCount(0);
    s.setSnapToTicks(true);
    s.setShowTickLabels(true);
    s.setShowTickMarks(true);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(s));
    stage.show();
}
```

But according to the issue : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18448 the solution cannot be applied until 8.0 release builds.

The trouble is that, seems, there is no way to solve the issue using manipulations on the left properties. Because all the left properties can manipulate the slider with linear value changing. Logarithmic value changing is reached via LabelFormatter, that is a trick.

There is also a feature on customisation : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27863

Comment: Oh thanks! Looks like just what I need. But unfortunately it shows labels like 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 2, 4, 8, 16.

Comment: What you say means, that labelFormatter was not applied. This means, that you use very old build. Which version of JFX is used?

Comment: Well, it was fixed in december of 2012 : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18448, so it is fixed only in 8.0 builds.

Comment: oh my gosh. `com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion()` says 2.2.21-b11. I'm going to update jfx now :)

Comment: "Fix Version/s : Lombard", this means, fix is not available in 2.2.*+versions. And, as I added in answer, seems, there is no way to make a logarithmic slider without applying of label formatter

Comment: How can I get 8.* build? I can't find any mentions on Oracle site. Is it possible to use javafx2 8.* with java7?

Comment: Build of JDK8 : https://jdk8.java.net/download.html, and as far as I remember, jfx8 cannot be used with jdk7

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like such simple problem has no simple solution.

Comment: The trouble is that there are many features are being done in jfx, and many bugs are introduced during that. So, the only way - to wait until technology stabilisation.